# How to set NSMutableDictionary to null

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I am using a NSMutableDictionary and am checking to see if it is empty (specifically null) using this:

```
if( [webContent isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
```

If it is true, I make a call to a web service and populate it with values that I process to display to the user.

Then I want to reset it to null for the next loop but I'm not sure how to reset it. I assume that reinitializing it like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary * webContent = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
```

has more overhead than setting it to null but please offer your advice.

Thanks

Comment: `NSMutableDictionary * webContent = [NSNull null];`
I prefer to set it to `nil` instead and check if its null.

Comment: Thanks. Do you agree with my if statement to check if it is null as well? And do you want to offer this as a answer?

Comment: Its a good practice to check for nil but before using it (however, nil does responds to all methods, so it won't just crash).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Apple documentation:

> The NSNull class defines a singleton object used to represent null values in collection objects (which don’t allow nil values).

For you, it's not the case. You should use `nil` instead of `NSNull`. Then testing will simply look like

```
if (webContent) {
    // do something
}
```

and reset like

```
webContent = nil;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Boris. Also, it compiles with no errors.

Answer (score 1):

`NSMutableDictionary * webContent = nil;`
You can set `null` to values of the dictionary, not the collection itself:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dict setObject:[NSNull null] forKey:@"myKey"];
```

Comment: Have you tested this? I'm getting an incompatible pointer type assigning to 'NSMutableDictionary*' from NSNULL * NonNull' error.